# How to execute a jar-packaged scala program via Apache Livy on Spark that responds with a result directly to a client request?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, curl, livy

What I intend to achieve is having a Scala Spark program (in a jar) receive a POST message from a client e.g. curl, take some argument values, do some Spark processing and then return a result value to the calling client.
From the Apache Livy documentation available I cannot find a way how I can invoke a compiled and packaged Spark program from a client (e.g. curl) via Livy in an interactive i.e. session mode. Such a request/reply scenario via Livy can be done with Scala code passed in plain text to the Spark shell. But how can I do it with a Scala class in a packaged jar?

```
curl -k --user "admin:mypassword" -v \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
-d @Curl-KindSpark_ScalaCode01.json \
"https://myHDI-Spark-Clustername.azurehdinsight.net/livy/sessions/0/statements" \
-H "X-Requested-By: admin"
```

Instead of Scala source code as data (`-d @Curl-KindSpark_ScalaCode01.json`) I would rather pass the path and filename of the jar-file and a ClassName and Argument values. But how?

Comment: I am also trying this, but my JAR file is on Local hard drive, I am using Livy locally . Can I invoke the JAR using session? 
I can run the JOB using Batches , but I want to do it using sessions.Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

- Make a uber jar of your Spark app with [sbt-assemby](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.
- Upload jar file from the previous step to your HDFS cluster:
  `hdfs dfs -put /home/hduser/PiNumber.jar /user/hduser`
- Execute your job via livy:
  `curl -X POST -d '{"conf": {"kind": "spark" , "jars": "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hduser/PiNumber.jar"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Requested-By: user" localhost:8998/sessions`
- check it:
  `curl localhost/sessions/0/statements/3`:

> {"id":3,"state":"available","output":{"status":"ok","execution_count":3,"data":{"text/plain":"Pi
>   is roughly 3.14256"}}}

p.s.

Spark Livy API for Scala/Java requires using an uber jar file. `sbt-assembly` doesn't make fat jar instantly, it annoys me. 
Usually, I use Python API of Livy for smoke tests and tweaking.

Sanity checks with Python:

- `curl localhost:sessions/0/statements -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"code":"print(\"Sanity check for Livy\")"}'`

You can put more complicated logic to field `code`. 
BTW, it's a way in which popular notebooks for Spark works - sending the source code to cluster via Livy.

Comment: Thx, I will try this out. In the meanwhile I found another solution:

Answer (score 0):

Thx, I will try this out. In the meanwhile I found another solution: 
$ curl -k --user "admin:" -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @Curl-KindSpark_BrandSampleModel_SessionSetup.json "https://mycluster.azurehdinsight.net/livy/sessions 
with a JSON file containing 
{
    "kind": "spark",
    "jars": ["adl://skylytics1.azuredatalakestore.net/skylytics11/azuresparklivy_2.11-0.1.jar"]
} 
and with the uploaded jar in the Azure Data Lake Gen1 account containing the Scala object and then post the statement 
$ curl -k --user "admin:myPassword" -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @Curl-KindSpark_BrandSampleModel_CodeSubmit.json "https://mycluster.azurehdinsight.net/livy/sessions/4/statements" -H "X-Requested-By: admin"
with the content 
{
    "code": "import AzureSparkLivy_GL01._; val brandModelSamplesFirstModel = AzureSparkLivyFunction.SampleModelOfBrand(sc, \"Honda\"); brandModelSamplesFirstModel"
}.

So I told Livy to start an interactive Spark session and load the specified jar and passed some code to invoke a member of the object in the jar. It works. Will check your advice too.